# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many query for all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

Given the following 2 models

```
class PropertyApplication
    has_and_belongs_to_many :applicant_profiles
end

class ApplicantProfile
    has_and_belongs_to_many :property_applications
end
```

I have a query that lists all `property_applications` and gets the collection of `applicant_profiles` for each `property_application`.

The query is as follows and it is very inefficient.

```
applications = PropertyApplication.includes(:applicant_profile).all.select |property_application| do
    property_application.applicant_profile_ids.include?(@current_users_applicant_profile_id)
do
```

assume `@current_users_applicant_profile_id` is already defined.

How can I perform one (or few) queries to achieve this?

I want to achieve something like this

```
PropertyApplication.includes(:applicant_profile).where('property_application.applicant_profiles IN (@current_users_applicant_profile))
```